# Reference for this "New is in the Old Concealed" quote that is attributed to Augustine?

Tags: reference-request, augustine

I've seen the quote, "The New is in the Old Concealed, the Old is in the New Revealed" (such as [a question here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/63481/what-did-augustine-mean-by-the-ot-is-the-nt-concealed-the-nt-is-the-ot-reveale) or the [second answer here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/9791/which-are-the-parts-of-the-old-testament-that-point-to-jesus/9796#9796)) or a variation, "The Old Testament is the New Testament concealed, and the New Testament is the Old Testament revealed" (such as in [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/33692/new-testament-poetry/33717#33717)) and I have typically seen this attributed to Augustine, though I haven't found its source.  I have only found these two related but non-identical statements of St. Augustine from "[On the Spirit and the Letter](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/1502.htm)."

> "This grace hid itself under a veil in the Old Testament, but it has been revealed in the New Testament" (from [chapter 27](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf105.xi.xxx.html))

and

> This is the righteousness of God, which was veiled in the Old Testament, and is revealed in the New (from chapter 18)

I actually originally heard this from a [Chuck Missler presentation](https://youtu.be/UYiuM43u0Q4?t=987) without attribution. And at [this Ligioner ministries article](https://www.ligonier.org/learn/articles/ancient-promises/), and many others, it is attributed to Augustine.

Where does this quote come from?

Comment: The Catholic Encyclopedia has similar quotations in chapters 18 and 27 of Augustine's "On the Spirit and the Letter"  http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/1502.htm

Comment: Thank you! My quote was from ch. 27. I'll add the ch. 18 quote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“In the Old Testament the New is concealed, in the New the Old is revealed” (Novum Testamentum in Vetere latet, Vetus Testamentum in Novo patet) literal: New Testament in the Old lies, the Old Testament in the New is clear. St. Augustine, Quaest. in Hept. 2,73: PL 34, 623; cf. DV 16.

In case the reference needs decoding; Quaestiones in Heptateuchum VII (Seven Questions Concerning the Heptateuch) Dated AD 419-420.

Comment: Thank you! And then what is the rest of that reference: "2,73: PL 34, 623; cf. DV 16"? Could you decode that for me too?

Comment: Away from my Library at the moment, but will get back to you as soon as I can. From memory it is in the Nicene and Post Nicene Library under works of Augustine.

Comment: wonderful, let me know!

Comment: 2.73 is the section in the Augustinian work. PL is an abbreviation for Migne, Jacques Paul, “Patrologia Latina”, 221 Vols, Imprimerie Catholique, Paris, 1844-1855. The companion volume is Migne, Jacques Paul, “Patrologia Graeca”, 85 Vols,  Imprimerie Catholique, Paris, 1856-1857. This is a several volume collection of all the Greek Fathers.